# how to use variable from subshell in shell

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

please could you help me how can I use value in variable number. This variable get value in while cycle and it is in subshell. So question is how can I use it in shell.
    number=0
    #blablabla

```
cat $WEDI_RC | while read line
    do  
       number=$(echo $line | grep $1 | awk -F'[ ]' '{print $3}')
       echo "in cycle"
       echo $number
    done
       echo "after while"
       echo $number
       ((number++))
       echo $number
       echo $1 `date +"%T"` $number >>$WEDI_RC
```

Comment: http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the pipe creates a subshell, which has it's own counting.

The question has surely be answered many times, so for the full explanation just the link to the bash FAQ:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

The usual workaround is to redirect input from the input file instead of piping it (and you'll even get rid of the useless use of `cat`):

```
while read -r line
do
    ...
done < "$WEDI_RC"
...
```

Comment: thank you, I have to rewrite last line to "done < $WEDI_RC" and now is everything working well.